# What is this pest attacking an avocado tree?

Tags: fruit-trees, pest-control, pests

I have a budding avocado tree* that is infested with these weird spiderweb-like things all over. I can not see an actual animal that is causing this.

I've treated it with soap water and alcohol and it *feels* like it's getting better, but I'm not sure.

What is this infestation, and do I need to do anything else to treat it?

<sub>* = at least I think it is an avocado tree. I've been told it could be a mango. I can't tell from the fruit yet. :)</sub>

[image]

Comment: carefully open up the casing inside the webbing. Anything inside?  Probably an insect or spider nursery.

Answer (score 2):

If you see webbing, but no insects, it's likely spider mites, and you need a hand lens or very good vision. Check all the "threads " on spider mites here.